# Полный список новых интерфейсов для каждого Android API

Tags: android

Всем Android разработчикам знакома формулировка

> Call requires API level {X} (current min is {< X}): {Where}

А если и не знакома, то точно будет.

Хотелось бы знать, при релизе нового апи где нибудь публикуется полный список новых интерфейсов, которые этот апи привносит?

Хотел вытащить информацию из кода, но её нет в JavaDoc или аннотациях, а подчёркивания в студии, похоже, делаются статическими анализаторами, что указывает на то, что эта информация где то точно существует так или иначе в том виде, в котором я её ищу.

Собственно вопрос в том, где, И может ли к ней получить доступ обычный разработчик?

Update:

Интересует не release notes и platform higlights в человекочитаемом виде, а что то, с чем можно было бы работать программно.

Comment: На сайте [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/30/changes) очень много различной информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так подумал: предупреждения выдаёт `lint`,
где-то он должен брать эту инфу,
а давай-ка посмотрим как он это делает.

Подсмотрев в исходники легко приходим к [этим строчкам](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/studio-master-release/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/ApiLookup.java#82):

```
/** Relative path to the api-versions.xml database file within the Lint installation */  
private static final String XML_FILE_PATH = "platform-tools/api/api-versions.xml"; //$NON-NLS-1$`
```

Находим этот файл в папке с установленным SDK по указанному пути.

Comment: Великолепно! Я только не знал, где брать исходники линта ) Уже начал рыть гитхаб. То, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Идёте [сюда](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels). Прокручиваете вниз до таблички. В этой табличке в правой колонке есть ссылки "Platform Highlights". Выбираете нужный API и кликаете. Там есть полное описание того что вошло в релиз.

Comment: Спасибо, направление правильное. Но, видимо, я не совсем ясно выразился. Разумеется я знаком с ресурсом developer.android.com и с информацией, которая там так красиво представлена. Однако я ищу то, с чем было бы удобно работать программно